# checkbox stored all option into database instead of one

Tags: javascript, php

Currently, my checkbox values is being stored as ["A","B","C"] into the database when I have only selected one option (eg C). Also, I have another question - is there any way possible to store it as ABC instead?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";

  var role;
});

function savenewuser() {
  var url = serverURL() + "/newadmin.php";
  checklist = new Array();
  $('input:checkbox[name="roles[]"]').each(function() {
    checklist.push($(this).val());
  });

  role = JSON.stringify(checklist);

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
      "role": role,
    },
    success: function(arr) {
      _getNewUserResult(arr);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("error");
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div><label for="rights">Rights</label></div>
<input type="checkbox" name="roles[]" value="A">Bookings
<input type="checkbox" name="roles[]" value="B">Incident Booking
<input type="checkbox" name="roles[]" value="C">Edit User
```

Comment: Because you're looping each checkbox and pushing their value to checklist, so all three are added

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're saving all the checkboxes:

```
$('input:checkbox[name="roles[]"]').each(function() {
    checklist.push($(this).val());
});
```

Try saving `:checked` ones only:

```
$('input:checkbox[name="roles[]"]:checked').each(function() {
    checklist.push($(this).val());
});
```